# Creating an object w/ text content from an DOM element and values from an input elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to create an array of objects with values of the text content of an HTML element (Label) from my page and the values from an form inputs.

The object gets displayed on console.log, but there is nothing from the values at all it displays "0".

```
//JavaScript
//answers value for the object
const answers = document.querySelectorAll("#questions input");

//questions value for the object
const questions = document.querySelectorAll("#questions label");

const questionsAnswers = [];
const wrongQuestions = [];
const displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");

  theQuestions.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
      for(let i = 0; i<questions.length; i++){

        //this is where the object gets created, where the problem occurs

            questionsAnswers.push({ question: questions[i].textContent, 
            answer: answers[i]});

        console.log(questionsAnswers[i]);
    }//end of for loop

        e.preventDefault();

 });// end of event listener


   //HTML
    <form id="theQuestions" style="height:500px">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="question1">What is the NBA team in Georgia?</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="question2">What is the name of the NFL team in 
          North Carolina?</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="question3">What team did Micheal Jordan play for? 
             </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question3">
        </div>    
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline 
           primary">Submit</button>        
    </form>



//I want the object to look like this 
 {
   answer: "text content of the first <label> element",
  question: "form input value from the first input element"
  },
  {
  answer: "text content of the 2nd <label> element",
  question: "form input value from the 2nd input element"
},
{
   answer: "text content of the 3rd <label> element",
   question: "form input value from the 3rd input element"
 }
```

Comment: as I see there are no value for your inputes! and you should use `questions[i].value' instead of `questions[i].textContent`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify this line:

questionsAnswers.push({ question: questions[i].textContent, 
            answer: answers[i]});

to

questionsAnswers.push({ question: questions[i].textContent, 
            answer: answers[i].value});

I hope it will work